# как действия в Notepad++ сделать одним скриптом Python?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Ввод

```
1609173056,74.63.248.149,80,71.6.233.107,80,0,51
1609173056,37.129.9.48,80,71.6.233.6,80,0,55
1609173056,104.73.188.191,80,71.6.233.99,80,0,48
1609173056,103.119.18.253,80,71.6.233.27,80,18597,117
1609173056,2.23.34.118,80,71.6.233.20,80,0,57
1609173056,23.39.197.80,80,71.6.233.92,80,0,59
1609173056,202.152.216.76,80,71.6.233.72,80,22924,52
1609173056,23.214.195.236,80,71.6.233.16,80,0,55
1609173056,167.206.137.231,80,71.6.233.47,80,0,49
1609173056,210.141.97.187,80,71.6.233.43,80,19029,53
1609173056,65.0.209.167,80,71.6.233.23,80,0,44
1609173056,180.167.226.53,80,71.6.233.55,80,9739,243
1609173056,54.229.156.172,80,71.6.233.4,80,8053,97
1609173056,172.81.101.119,80,71.6.233.127,80,0,56
1609173056,52.194.159.85,80,71.6.233.123,80,0,232
1609173056,119.193.196.206,80,71.6.233.128,80,0,52
1609173056,46.101.185.113,80,71.6.233.21,80,0,46
1609173056,220.77.159.41,80,71.6.233.13,80,0,53
1609173056,110.50.237.10,80,71.6.233.4,80,54321,116
1609173056,104.90.198.57,80,71.6.233.25,80,0,50
1609173056,23.201.245.159,80,71.6.233.57,80,0,58
1609173056,209.84.20.141,80,71.6.233.99,80,59875,60
1609173056,23.60.205.148,80,71.6.233.24,80,0,49
1609173056,167.99.135.39,80,71.6.233.25,80,0,46
1609173056,78.116.114.199,80,71.6.233.95,80,4766,47
```

Вывод

```
    74.63.248.149:80
    71.6.233.107:80
    и тд.
```

в Notepad++ привожу ипы в такой вид очень долго такими регулярками:
сначала удаляю первые 10 цифр ^\d{10}, затем заменяю запятые ,80, на :80; затем переношу ; в новую строку \n
затем помечаю закладкой \d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3} строки без закладки удаляю .

как действия в Notepad++ сделать одним скриптом Python?

Comment: Вместо длинного и непонятного описания действий в блокноте лучше бы написал, что из исходной строки должно попасть в результат.

Comment: написал ожидаемый результат каждый ип в новой строке

Comment: Смотри: тому, кто прочитал твой вопрос, нужно сидеть и сравнивать исходную строчку с результатом и пытаться вычислить, что должно попасть из первой во вторую и по каким правилам. А там еще и из одной строчки получается две, да знаки заменяются, что совсем не упрощает вычисления. Хотя ты мог просто добавить в вопрос "нужно взять то и это, и вот так форматировать".

Answer (score 1):

Используем в регэкспе 4 группы, которые подставляем в шаблон:

```
import re

src = '1609173056,74.63.248.149,80,71.6.233.107,80,0,51'
'{}:{}\n{}:{}'.format(
    *re.findall(r'.+?,(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),(.+?),' , src)[0]
)

> '74.63.248.149:80\n71.6.233.107:80'
```

Comment: не работает скрипт. Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: @MrGarison ну да, всё правильно, отработал успешно и завершился без кода ошибки. Что не так?

Comment: не могу найти результат отработанного? в консоли пусто. Запускаю скрипт через Pycharm

Comment: @MrGarison если хотите распечатать - поместите результат в `print()`